Quickfix sendingTime of incoming market data incremental refresh messages lags actual time after a while
I am using quickfix python and connecting to an exchange via TCP connection to receive order book market data updates from them.
I am receiving market data incremental refresh messages (MsgType=X) at quite a high frequency from the exchange server. Originally there will be no difference between the receiving time and the time shown in field 52 (sendingTime).
From the FIX logs, the difference between receiving time and sendingTime gradually increases until it becomes a 1 hour difference as shown here : 20241112-21:00:01.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.452=20241112-19:51:16.421
What are possible reasons for this mismatch between the sendingTime recorded in the FIX logs and the actual time i received this message

You are processing the messages too slow and they pile up in a buffer or queue?

@ChristophJohn Yup I removed the code processing my messages and that fixes the issue. Thanks!

QuickFIX handles messages on a single thread -- it won't start processing message B until it finishes processing message A.
Therefore, it is very important your QF callback implementations return quickly, or else you will start to see lag after handling a high volume of messages.
And I suspect this is exactly what is happening to you.  You have logic in your onMessage(MarketDataIncrementalRefresh) (or whatever the Python version of that is) that is taking too long to complete, and it's causing a backup.
(One thing that does surprise me is that your app hasn't crashed out long before you hit the 1-hour lag.  The default MaxLatency configuration is 120 seconds.  Have you upped that value to a very large number?)
One solution:
Have your onMessage callback push incoming X messages to a queue, and have a separate thread consume these messages off that queue and do the processing that you need.
And of course, figure out way to speed up your processing logic.

Thanks for help! Yes I have set MaxLatency to 240 seconds. Will try out the solutions mentioned

That’s only 4 minutes!

Hmm seems like I have set checkLatency=N, which is why I am processing messages from 1 hour ago. However, when I set checkLatency=Y, even a simple logic of parsing the fix messages and appending it to a queue results in my quickfix client logging out with the error: 'SENDINGTIME ACCURACY PROBLEM' after running for a few minutes, as the incoming message sendingTime lags the current time by more than 120 seconds

Well, CheckLatency=N explains that part.  Regarding the "accuracy problem" as you are describing it, have you tried recording metrics for how much time your code is spending in the onMessage callback?  Are you taking in messages faster than you can process them?

Hi Grant I have not recorded metrics but that is definitely the issue. My function which parses the fix message into a python string is not fast enough. Am currently exploring quickfix java to see if that speeds things up

I have tried storing the raw fix.Message object in a queue, but for some reason when i pop the items from the queue, it runs into odd behaviour and my program stops, whereas when i store the fix messages as a string into a queue, and i try popping the queue from another thread, everything works as expected. However parsing the fix message into a string is currently a bottleneck for me
